# MySql join tables without common column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables: `users`, `schedule`, `work_hours`.

I want to receive user data only from days when they didn't have the "#successor" or "#confirming" comment

```
select u.id, u.username, u.rate, COUNT(w.id) as days_in_work,
    SUM(w.success) as user_success,
    SUM(time_to_sec(w.accept_stop) - time_to_sec(w.accept_start)) / 3600 as user_sum
```

Query result should look like this:

```
| id  | username | rate  | days_in_work | user_success | user_sum |
| --- | -------- | ----- | ------------ | ------------ | -------- |
| 1   | Adam     | 13.37 | 4            | 58           | 32.0000  |
| 2   | Artur    | 14    | 3            | 46           | 24.0000  |
```

The problem is that the 'schedule' table does not have a column that would allow a direct link between the appropriate `day_comment` and the corresponding date of the `work_hours` table.
Is there any way to achieve this?
My attempts so far have stopped on the following query:

```
select u.id, u.username, u.rate, COUNT(w.id) as days_in_work,
    SUM(w.success) as user_success,
    SUM(time_to_sec(w.accept_stop) - time_to_sec(w.accept_start)) / 3600 as user_sum
from work_hours as w
    inner join users as u on u.id = w.id_user
    inner join schedule as s on s.id_user = u.id
where u.user_type_id in (1, 2) 
    and w.status in (4, 5) 
    and u.department_info_id = 2
    and s.year in (2021) 
    and (w.date between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-07')
    and CASE
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Monday' THEN s.monday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Tuesday' THEN s.tuesday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Wednesday' THEN s.wednesday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Thursday' THEN s.thursday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Friday' THEN s.friday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Saturday' THEN s.saturday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
        WHEN dayname(w.date) = 'Sunday' THEN s.sunday_comment not in ('#successor', '#confirming')
    END
group by u.id
order by u.username asc
```

It works "almost" perfectly, but probably does not distinguish relevant records in 'work_hours' and overwrites / skips them.

[Here's a sandbox with the needed code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/35dPPA2QL8StYuWWnwnyHz/2)

Comment: Please add your desired output based on the fiddle data

Comment: The `work_hours` table has a `date` column - you can easily find the year, week number and day of the week. Of course, it would be better if table `schedule` was using dates instead of year/week_num - but even now the task is not impossible.

Comment: @P.Salmon I added an example query result in edit

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes, I tried adding an additional condition like `s.week_num in ( noOfWeeks )` but that doesn't solve the problem. I need advice on how to associate the appropriate date with 'work_hours' with the appropriate comment in the 'schedule', because I suspect that if the query encounters the first day meeting the condition (or not), it assigns the entire week.

Comment: When does your week start - sunday or monday, is jan 1-7 week 1?

Comment: @P.Salmon Week starts in monday, just like columns are and yeah, january 1-7 was week 1

Comment: 'january 1-7 was week 1 ' - that's unfortunate mondays are therefore day 4 in the week number (eg 2021-01-04') and I'm not clear what/how days 1-3 and 5-7 represent in our data.

Comment: @P.Salmon This is where the problem lies, there is no connection between the date and the given comment in the schedule table, all you can do is format the date to week number, year and weekday name, which I have already tried in query above.